# Bulk update case when but for distinct ids matching particular conditional

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code snippet where I want to update based on individual row from TABLE_B matching the conditional, then update field in TABLE A per match. If I do a single update, it works fine. However, the problem occurs if there is a match for the first record, it performs the same update on the second id as well. How can I do a distinct bulk update for a group of ids that match the conditional? :

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET FOO
        = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
           WHERE ID in (‘123’, ‘456’)
           AND (START_DATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND END_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)))
           THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ),WHERE ID in (‘123’, ‘456’);
```

One thing to note is I'm hoping to dynamically pass in a random number of ids (via code), so it won't be just two ids but can be many more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Merge Into to get it done. There is no sample data provided - I will create some just as an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE
    TABLE_A (ID, FOO) AS
        (   Select '123' "ID", 'X' "FOO" From Dual Union All
        Select '456', 'X' From Dual Union All
        Select '789',  'X' From Dual 
        );
--  ID  FOO
--  --- ---
--  123 X
--  456 X
--  789 X
CREATE TABLE 
    TABLE_B AS
        (   Select '123' "ID",  To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "START_DATE", To_Date('31.12.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select '456',  To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('30.06.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select '789',  To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('31.12.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual 
        );
--  ID  START_DAT END_DATE 
--  --- --------- ---------
--  123 01-JAN-23 31-DEC-23
--  456 01-JAN-23 30-JUN-23
--  789 01-JAN-23 31-DEC-23
```

Now we can join the tables and define values for FOO column:

```sql
Select        a.ID "ID",  
            Case When b.ID Is Null Then 'N' Else 'Y' End "FOO"
From            TABLE_A a
Left Join   TABLE_B b ON(b.ID = a.ID And a.ID In('123', '456') And
            TRUNC(SYSDATE) Between b.START_DATE And b.END_DATE)
Where         a.ID In('123', '456')
--  ID  FOO
--  --- ---
--  123 Y
--  456 N
```

The above query could be used by MERGE INTO to update column FOO

```sql
Merge Into TABLE_A t
Using   (   Select        a.ID "ID", --b.START_DATE, b.END_DATE, 
                      Case When b.ID Is Null Then 'N' Else 'Y' End "FOO"
          From          TABLE_A a
          Left Join     TABLE_B b ON(b.ID = a.ID And a.ID In('123', '456') And
                      TRUNC(SYSDATE) Between b.START_DATE And b.END_DATE)
          Where           a.ID In('123', '456')
        ) x ON(x.ID = t.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.FOO = x.FOO
Where t.ID In('123', '456')
--  2 rows merged.
```

You should adjust this to meet your context. Ensure that the rows are joined 1 to 1 to avoid error message and be sure of addressing the right rows in the table a. That could be done within the used query or in ON condition or in Where clause or any of them combined,

```sql
--  R e s u l t :
Select * From TABLE_A
--  ID  FOO
--  --- ---
--  123 Y
--  456 N
--  789 X
```